# MenuInflater feature doesn't work on other devices?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
    blowUp.inflate(R.menu.help_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.help:
        Intent z = new Intent(EpicShit.this, Help.class);
        startActivity(z);
        break;
    case R.id.exit:
        finish();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is the code that i'm running for the menuinflater. I'm currently using a HTC One S and this works, as i get what it should, which are "Help" & "Exit". But when i tried this on a Samsung S2, there isn't even a place for me to choose these 2 options from. It's just not there. Could this be because we have different versions (my program doesn't support older versions)? Or am i programmatically incorrect? Also, i don't have the code for this right now, but it's a similar problem: soundpool and setAlpha don't work on the S2, but works on HTC One S.

Comment: Where do You expect to have these option on Samsung S2? BTW, have You tried menu button on S2?

Comment: Which Android versions do your phones have??

Comment: Shoot...my friend didn't know she has a menu button. Sorry about that! What about my soundpool and setalpha problems?

Comment: i have 4.0.4, my friend's samsung s2's version is 2.3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you put in your menu/main.xml

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

will appear in the action bar for Android 4.0+, while

```
android:showAsAction="Never"
```

will only show up when the Menu key is pressed.

The Galaxy S2 doesn't show the action bar (because it's a Gingerbread phone), while One S does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My friend didn't know she had a menu button, and we're skyping so i can't really physically help her.